# Ajax function with location.reload acting weird

Tags: ajax

I have a function that sends values to the db, the function works great until I include the `success` function with a `location.reload()`. Then it sends empty values.. sometimes though... sometimes it works fine, but I should be able to rely on it.

Any suggestions?

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'core/manage_articles.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    blog:title,
    title:title,
    text:text,
    lat:lat,
    lng:lng,
    success: function() {
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Unlikely related to reload in success callback. Check if your title, text, lat and lng vars are empty in moment when you call $.ajax. You actually send function as data param, but I think it should be serialized, not called.

Comment: No, I was wrong, its called. zozo is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you didn't say what lib you are using so I'll just go on a semiwild guess (might not be right):

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'core/manage_articles.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    blog:title,
    title:title,
    text:text,
    lat:lat,
    lng:lng
  },
   success: function() {
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

Try it like this.

Comment: my pleasure. also as a tip... next time say the lib you are using ;). have fun.